# like putting two buttons centered in kivy?

Tags: python, button, center, kivy

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class body(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(body,self).__init__(**kwargs);
        self.orientation = 'vertical';
        lst = ['button'];
        cont = len(lst);
        for d in lst:
            eval('self.'+d+'()');
        self.add(cont);

    def button(self):
        self.hLayout_1 = AnchorLayout(orientation='horizontal');
        self.button_1 = Button(text='conectar',size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,100));
        self.button_2 = Button(text='enviar',size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,100));
        self.hLayout_1.add_widget(self.button_1);
        self.hLayout_1.add_widget(self.button_2);

    def add(self,num):
        for n in range(num):
            eval('self.add_widget(self.hLayout_'+str(n+1)+')');

class Client(App):
    def build(self):
        b = body();
        return b


Client().run();
```

buttons leave me one on another, as I fix this?

or also with gridlayout

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class body(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(body,self).__init__(**kwargs);
        self.pos_hint={'center_x':.5}
        self.orientation = 'vertical';
        lst = ['button'];
        cont = len(lst);
        for d in lst:
            eval('self.'+d+'()');
        self.add(cont);

    def button(self):
        self.hLayout_1 = GridLayout(cols=2);
        self.button_1 = Button(text='conectar',size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,100));
        self.button_2 = Button(text='enviar',size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,100));
        self.hLayout_1.add_widget(self.button_1);
        self.hLayout_1.add_widget(self.button_2);

    def add(self,num):
        for n in range(num):
            eval('self.add_widget(self.hLayout_'+str(n+1)+')');

class Client(App):
    def build(self):
        b = body();
        return b


Client().run();
```

I can focus as the two buttons correctly?

I've tried with various layout, but it has not worked, maybe it's because it still did not quite understand that sirver "size_hint" appreciate some help.

Comment: 1) Are you asking how to make two buttons appear next to each other? Not quite sure what you want here. 2) You shouldn't use semicolons (`;`) in Python - they are only used to put multiple statements on a single line, which is bad form anyway. 3) `eval()` is slow and insecure. Use `getattr()` to get attributes by string.

Comment: if I want a button that is next to another, and the two in the center, focused on a layout, pretended not to be upset, I will try not to put the; at the end, so thanks also to "eval ()" I will use getattr ().
Then how one could get to appear side by side and in the center? And what would be the correct layout?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think this is what you want:

```
class Body(FloatLayout): # capitalize class per convention, and extend FloatLayout instead of BoxLayout
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Body, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # create a sized BoxLayout
        centerlayout = BoxLayout(size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 100))
        # create and add buttons - they will be sized automatically in the BoxLayout
        button_1 = Button(text='conectar')
        button_2 = Button(text='enviar')
        centerlayout.add_widget(button_1)
        centerlayout.add_widget(button_2)
        # add the BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(centerlayout)
        # center the BoxLayout to our center - this needs to be bound, as Body is not yet positioned
        self.bind(center=centerlayout.setter('center'))
```

You should also look into the [kv language](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html); it makes things much easier, especially as your widgets get more complex.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
body = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 100
        center: root.center

        Button:
            text: 'conectar'
        Button:
            text: 'enviar'
''')
```

[image: demo image]

Comment: Does it work for you? If it is you should have accepted it as the answer for this question. I am testing it :)

Answer (score 1):

> buttons leave me one on another, as I fix this?

This is because you use an AnchorLayout. It aligns its children to the anchor, not to each other, so it's correct behaviour that they are placed in the same place.

The solution is to not use the AnchorLayout at all.

> I can focus as the two buttons correctly?

Can you explain what you mean by this?

Also:

- With python, you don't need semicolons at the ends of lines.
- `eval('self.'+d+'()');` is bad style, you could use `getattr` instead, e.g. `getattr(self, d)()`.

Comment: I know it's not necessary but I like to write the code as
Then how could focus buttons? What would be the right way?